# Aws multipart unable to pause (t.forEach is not a function) Uppy

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, uppy

I am using [uppy](https://uppy.io/docs/aws-s3-multipart/) AWS multipart to upload files on AWS.

When I pause the upload I am facing the below error:

> [Uppy] [12:47:13] Failed to upload Screencast.mp4 t.forEach is not a function
> [Uppy] [12:47:13] t.forEach is not a function

```html
<script src="https://releases.transloadit.com/uppy/v1.27.0/uppy.min.js"></script>

<script>
  var uppy = Uppy.Core().use(Uppy.Dashboard, {
    inline: true,
    target: '#drag-drop-area'
  }).use(
    Uppy.AwsS3Multipart, {
      companionUrl: '/my-companionUrl/',
      limit: 4,
    }
  )
</script>
```

Comment: I am also facing the same issue, have you got any solution ?

Comment: @Kesava you need to fix this issue on server(backend) end.

Comment: @Kesava I have created code for aws multipart you can refer to this  https://github.com/rahul08M/aws-s3-multipart-django

Comment: Uppy simply does not work for > 5GB uploads. The proof is the dozens of complains and zero reference to any working solution, anywhere on the internet. I am tired of just seeing questions and zero answers, I'll be  looking for other solutions, more technically capable than limited Uppy.